# Looking through a list for a certain or relatively close value

Tags: python, search, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Type     Mag     ra     dec
3        24.6    223.2  50.833
6        24.5    223.19 50.834
```

With more than 500 values per column. I want to look for a certain value and anything close to it. I have the values 223.2516 for the ra and 58.0538 for the dec. These values were converted and they may not be exactly like this in the csv data file. I therefore, want anything that's close to the values I'm looking for. If I'm looking for 223.2516 then anything that has at least 223.25 should come out as a result this way i can compare which one is the closest.

All I have now is to ask python to do a search i.e.

```
223.2516 in [row[2] for row in data]
```

But this only returns true of this exact value is there which may or may not be there. Like I said, I want all values that are close to that one with the first 5 numbers: "223.25".

I tried adding an asterisk after 223.25 as such

```
223.2 * in [row[2] for row in data]
```

but all I get is

```
File "<ipython-input-16-d185380219a6>", line 1
    223.2 * in [row[2] for row in data]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the whole code:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *

data = np.genfromtxt('result.csv',delimiter=',',skip_header=1, dtype=float)
223.2516 in [row[2] for row in data]
```

The value to be found will obviously be through user input, I just haven't added that part yet. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you define "close"? By absolute difference, or ratio? E.g. is 99999 close to 100000?

Comment: You probably want something like `[ row[2] if abs(row[2]-223.25)<0.01 for row in data ]`.  Then you can change "0.01" for whatever you define as "close".

Comment: It depends a little on what you want as the output.  Just the value? An index into the array of the ones that are "close"?

Comment: That worked perfectly and I get a huge list of False and True statements corresponding to every row in the column. Is there a way to only show the 'True' statements along with the row number?

Comment: I think my syntax was backwards... `[ row[2] for row in data if abs(row[2]-223.25)<0.01 ]`

Comment: Wait, is there still no one to output the row number in which the value is from?

Answer (score 0):

yes, what you want is something like:

```
arr = r_[1:10]
[a for a in arr if abs(a-5) < 2 ]
```

This results in [4,5,6], for example.